# Handling errors in aws lambda in serverless

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm trying to return errors from my lambda functions but for all of the errors it just returns status `502` with message `Internal server error`. Previously it was just returning `cors` error for all types of returned errors. After adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'` in api gateway responses, i'm getting `502` error. I've logged thrown errors in catch block & i can see the specific errors in `CloudWatch`. I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557042/handling-errors-in-aws-lambda-function-with-api-gateway) but that didn't help anyway. Please note that instead of using `callback` i'm using `async await`. Also i've tried with & without `lambda-proxy` integration but the response is same. Do i need to configure something else in case of `lambda-proxy`?

```
const test = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const error = { status: 400, message: 'my custom error' };
    throw error;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('==== error ====', error);

    return createErrorResponse(error.status || 500, error.errors || error.message);
  }
```

createErrorResponse

```
const createErrorResponse = (statusCode, message, stack={}) => ({
  statusCode,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    error: message
  }),
  stack: JSON.stringify({ stack })
});

export default createErrorResponse;
```

serverless.yml

```
test:
    handler: api/index.test
    timeout: 360
    events:
      - http:
          path: test-lambda-api
          method: post
          cors: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Lambda proxy integration with API Gateway, the response from Lambda is expected in a certain format:

```
var response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "my_header": "my_value"
    },
    "body": JSON.stringify(responseBody),
    "isBase64Encoded": false
};
```

Include your `stack` JSON key inside the `body` itself. You can also refer to this post for more info: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/

Also, you should enable debug logs for the API Gateway stage which will give a better understanding of what is sent and received from the API GW integration.

Comment: Only the missing `isBase64Encoded` key was creating issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Kamran Arshad How did you end up sending the "stack" JSON key?

Comment: I was using it for development purposes only and not to return with response but i think this should be handled by adding it in body as you've mentioned